# Detect if there is a number at the beginning of an input

Tags: python, file, terminal-emulator

I am making an apple ][ (2) emulator, and I am working on the last part, writing the code

What I want to happen is when somebody inputs the following:

```
20 x = 0
```

In the file, on line 20, it should put:

```
x = 0
```

When looking it up, I cant find anything to help with it, other then checking the whole string for numbers.

The 3 problems  are:

1. writing to the correct file line
2. not writing the file line number to the file line
3. removing any blank lines

an example for 3 is:

Well say this is the file were using:

```
x = 0



while True:
    
    
    
    
    if x = 9:
        
        
        
        
        x = 0
        
    
    
    
    x += 1
```

if somebody inputs '20', the file then should look like this:

```
x = 0



while True:
    
    
    
    
    if x = 9:
        
        
        
        
        x = 0
```

Rather then this:

```
x = 0



while True:
    
    
    
    
    if x = 9:
        
        
        
        
        x = 0
```

Comment: This question is too vague.  Please post actual code, so we don't have to guess what you meant.

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't have any code yet, I cant find anything on how to do it, and I don't have any ideas on how to do it either.

Comment: Beware, you are mixing different aspects. Your question could be related to a Basic language interpretor where all lines in a program are preceded by a line number, or to a text editor where someone could insert a line at a given position. They have always been different environments for a reason... If you want to emulate how old systems used to work, refrain to adding too many new functionalities.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am not adding new functionallity. In fact, I still need to add more stuff to it.

Comment: Split the text input on spaces using `split()`, then grab the first part and check if it is numeric.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: You should first define exactly how your app should behave. Are there different modes? What is the syntax in each mode? There is a long time I have not used an Apple ][, and I cannot remember how it worked... BTW if you want to process complex input, parsers like PLY could help.

Answer (score 0):

You use .split

You take the obj 0, then use that for placements
as far as placing on a specific line goes, you have to make the whole file a list, then write to the list object, then rewrite it to the file.